# Windows pipenv shell don't work

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pipenv

I am trying to use pipenv and when I try to activate virtual environment, it seems like it won't work.

process:

```
pipenv install django
pipenv lock 
pipenv shell
```

and the cmd text turn white and show this

```
C:\Users\_monster\Desktop\skill\django_frontend\backend
λ pipenv shell -c
Launching subshell in virtual environment. Type 'exit' to return.
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

and I try to do something inside, it won't work anything. what wrong?

Comment: have you tried executing in a path that does **not** contain a space?

Comment: sorry i dont get what you mean by that

Comment: i think i got it work thank you